# Is there a way to simiulate SQL server error responses/states without writing something that brings down the DB?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

The other day on our production DB we had a few bad queries come to light that caused some blocking in our productions systems. While these queries have been fixed, there was another problem that somehow our application started displaying the message "A type 1000 server error has occurred". I'm trying to update our application to appropriately handle this, unfortunately I don't seem to be able to easily regenerate the state SQL server was in that caused this error. Is there a way to "short circuit" a request to SQL so the DB will give a response but indicate that it is in a "locked" or "unable to execute" state?

Comment: You could hack up the response object of whatever DB library you're using to recreate an error state internally within the handle.

Comment: Have you looked at using `RAISERROR` to generate error simulations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: I've looked at RaiseError, but it doesn't quite do what i want. Our application can handle a problem with an individual query, which is all I can really simulate with that. When the DB starts locking some queries execute fine while others fail and its the overall situation I'm trying to simulate

Comment: Hacking up the response object could work, but I was hoping for something a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you could use [TRY...Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) to return whatever response you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Mock Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) are the "BestWay(tm)" to test this type of behavior. If you don't have a testing framework (e.g. [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/)) to facilitate this, there are fewer options.

- You can hack up the response object, like @Marc B suggested, which is
  like using Mock Objects, but in a less-formal way.
- You can also set up a dev environment which points to an instance
  of SqlServer that you can abuse.